# Random Element as input and get the Value

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

I don't know if it's a duplicated Question cause I've found nothing and actually I didn't know what Keywords should I've been searching.

I want to have a class which gets an Element as input and then shows the Value of that Element.

for Example:

```
public void showValue(Object obj){
    System.out.printLn("output: " + obj.getValue());
}
```

and then:

```
NativeSelect ns=new NativeSelect();
TextField tf=new TextField();

ns.addValue("Name");
ns.select("Name");

tf.setValue("LastName");

showValue(ns);
showValue(tf);
```

and have this output:

```
output: Name
output: LastName
```

could maybe someone help me or give me an idea how should i do that!
I'm new to Java and started programming after a long time.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a function that can print the value of every field. Like this:

```
public static void showValue(Field f) {
   System.out.println("output: "f.getValue()); //Will print it via console
   new Notification("output: "+f.getValue()).show(Page.getCurrent()); 
   //Will show a text box in your current page
}
```

As from Field docs ([link](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Field.html)), every field has a `getValue()`. All that you should take care is that value types that you use in your fields should have overriden `toString` so this method doesn't show the default `toString`.

Comment: Thanks alot @Shirkam. It was a great help to me!